# Make bootable usb on ubuntu

Tags: bootloader

Ubuntu16.04  is installed on my laptop and now I want to remove ubuntu and install windows. I have windows iso file  so I made a bootable usb pen drive using "disk image writer"

feature on ubuntu. But when I am trying to boot from usb drive it shows that "installation media is invalid"
So how can I make a bootable usb drive of Windows on ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

Use [Winusb](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html).  It's no longer in the Ubuntu repository.  You can get it via ppa source:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install winusb
```

Comment: When I am trying to run firest command, it is giving " Error: need a repository as argument"

Comment: The first command is a repository.  the `$` sign is representing the terminal prompt.  Be sure to copy the rest of the line exact and it will add the repository... `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`